# Present Continuous (personal initiative), Present Simple (a voice of authority)?

Tags: tense

#### Do you agree that when we use Present Continuous and Present Simple for future plans Present Continuous conveys a personal initiative while Present Simple conveys some outward instructions?

> Is my understanding correct that:

1 Are you working tomorrow?

Can mean "are you going to work tomorrow?" "have you made up your mind to work tomorrow?"

2 Do you work tomorrow?

Is more likely to mean "Is tomorrow the day when you have to to go to work because it's timetabled?" or "because it is inevitable?"

3 Are we having a class tomorrow? (if put by a student to the teacher)

Can mean "Are we going to have a class/lesson tomorrow?" The class hasn't been fixed yet.

4 Do we have a class tomorrow/lesson tomorrow?

Can mean "Is a lesson scheduled for tomorrow?

Comment: Sounds right to me. Not sure a full answer would be more than just "yeah, sure".

Comment: The matter is that the British don't accept "Do you work tomorrow?" or "When do you go to work tomorrow"? Basically, present simple with tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, I guess I should add that I'm in America.